# gdalinfo on each tile of a vrt

Tags: gdal, vrt, gdalinfo

Is there a way to use the gdalinfo tool to calculate the statistics of each tile in a vrt?

I would like to get a set of descriptive statistics (min, max, mean, etc.) for each of the slabs that make up my vrt simply (i.e. without scripting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, gdalinfo treats the VRT as a single file.